# Binning Hours in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
datetime     Normaltime
---------    ----------
1443446880   2015-09-28 06:28:00
1443450600   2015-09-28 07:30:00
1443451740   2015-09-28 07:49:00
```

One column is in UNIX time, the other is in normal hours.

I would like to create 4 new columns for different hour windows, how would I create these?

I'd like it to look something like this

```
datetime     Normaltime             Daypart
---------    ----------            ---------
1443446880   2015-09-28 06:28:00    Morning
1443450600   2015-09-28 07:30:00    Morning
1443451740   2015-09-28 07:49:00    Morning
1443468600   2015-09-28 12:30:00    Afternoon
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean create new column `Daypart` with 4 different values for hour windows? What would those windows be?

Comment: Oh yeah, one column, 4 dayparts. 0-6, 6-9, 9-4, 4-11:59

Comment: How would you like to label those four parts?

Comment: overnight, morning, afternoon, prime, respectively

Comment: Hour is in 24-hour standard?

Comment: yes, the hours are in 24 hour-standard

Comment: Extract the hours and then use `cut`.

Comment: @Gregor A very good hint. I implemeted it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R:

```
df$Daypart <- ifelse( format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) >= "00" & format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) < "06", "Overnight",
ifelse( format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) >= "06" & format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) < "09","Morning",
ifelse( format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) >= "09" & format( as.POSIXct( df$Normaltime ),"%H" ) < "16", "Afternoon","Prime")
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try (using hint of Gregor):

```
library(lubridate)

df$Daypart <- cut(hour(ymd_hms(df$Normaltime)), c(0,6,9,14,Inf),
    c("Overnight", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Prime"))
df
    datetime          Normaltime   Daypart
1 1443446880 2015-09-28 06:28:00 Overnight
2 1443450600 2015-09-28 07:30:00   Morning
3 1443451740 2015-09-28 07:49:00   Morning
4 1443468600 2015-09-28 12:30:00 Afternoon
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [findInterval](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) to do it in a fairly simple manner;

```
#     datetime          Normaltime
# 1 1443446880 2015-09-28 05:59:59
# 2 1443446880 2015-09-28 06:00:00
# 3 1443446880 2015-09-28 06:28:00
# 4 1443450600 2015-09-28 07:30:00
# 5 1443451740 2015-09-28 07:49:00
# 6 1443451780 2015-09-28 15:00:00
# 7 1443451780 2015-09-28 16:00:00

df$Daypart = (c('overnight', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'prime')
               [findInterval(hour(df$Normaltime), c(-Inf, 6, 9, 16, Inf))])

#     datetime          Normaltime   Daypart
# 1 1443446880 2015-09-28 05:59:59 overnight
# 2 1443446880 2015-09-28 06:00:00   morning
# 3 1443446880 2015-09-28 06:28:00   morning
# 4 1443450600 2015-09-28 07:30:00   morning
# 5 1443451740 2015-09-28 07:49:00   morning
# 6 1443451780 2015-09-28 15:00:00 afternoon
# 7 1443451780 2015-09-28 16:00:00     prime
```